# Where do I connect thermostat C-wire to the Peerless boiler relay panel?

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, boiler

I’m looking to replace my existing thermostats (two zones) with smart thermostats that require a C-wire.  The current thermostats do not have the C-wire connected, but the wire is already present in the wire bundle.   I have both an HVAC system and an oil burner (Peerless WBV -03 Boiler).  The oil burner has a wiring relay panel, where I can see the wiring for each zone, as well as the unused C-wire for each zone (green wire wrapped around the wire bundle).  However, on the relay panel, each zone only has terminals for R and W wire connections (no C terminal).  On the other side of the relay panel, there are a bunch of 120V terminals, some of them labeled as zones 1 and 2 circulators.  The only two terminals on that side that are not cabled to are labeled ZC and ZR.  I’m trying to figure out where I need to connect the C-wires from thermostat zones 1 and 2 to.  Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.  Please see the pictures of the oil burner relay panel I have uploaded.

[image: Oil Burner Relay Panel]
[image: Oil Burner Relay Panel2]
[image: Oil Burner Relay Panel3]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

C is the 24V common, so it's probably at
the terminal marked "COM" here.

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you very much for your feedback.  I have one additional question that I'm hoping you can answer...  When connecting the C-wire to the oil burner relay panel, do both the HVAC and oil burner need to be powered off at the circuit breaker panel?  When I power off the oil burner, does that also cut power to the two thermostats?

Comment: Thermostat power comes though the yellow and red wires in the middle picture, so if you turn off the AC supply to this box the thermostats will be powered off.